# Manual grub2-mkconfig adds code not found in autogenerated grub.cfg

Tags: fedora, grub2

I made some changes to `/etc/default/grub` and ran `grub2-mkconfig -o <path>`.  Comparing this to the old `grub.cfg` I can see that it's added the contents of `/etc/grub.d/01_menu_auto_hide`, which was entirely missing from the old cfg file, and also that the contents of the `00_header` section are slightly different.  Is there something besides `grub2-mkconfig` I should be using?

My system is Fedora 29.